# What is the best way to get an actor from the context in Akka?

Tags: scala, akka

I tried two ways:

- Use `Await.result`

  *Await.result(context.actorSelection("akka://Post/user/John").resolveOne(3 seconds), 10 seconds)*
- Get future value manually

  *context.actorSelection("akka://Post/user/John").resolveOne(3 seconds).value.get.get*

But I have that feeling I'm doing something wrong.

Code of my actor:

```
def receive: Receive = {
  case "msg" ⇒ {

    ...

    val reader = Await.result(context.actorSelection("akka://Post/user/John").resolveOne(3 seconds), 10 seconds)
    reader ! data
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **never block inside an Actor's `receive` loop**. At best it wastes resources, at worse it could lead to a deadlock where the resolution cannot happen because all threads in the thread pool are already in use.

Your best options are:

**Send the message directly to the actorSelection**

You can just call `tell` directly on the actor selection. Of course, you don't know if the resolution succeeds. And if this happens a lot, it's certainly less efficient than having the actorRef hang around.

```
context.actorSelection("akka://Post/user/John").resolveOne(3 seconds) ! data
```

**Resolve the selection asynchronously**

Given that you have a `Future` on your hand you could either send your message in the `onComplete` or use `pipeTo` to send the resolved ref back to the yourself:

*send on resolution*

```
def receive = {
  case data:Data =>
    context.actorSelection("akka://Post/user/John").resolveOne(3 seconds)
      .onComplete {
         case Success(reader) => reader ! data
         case Failure(e) => // handle failure
      }
}
```

*pipe to self*

```
case class Deferred(data: Data, ref: ActorRef)

var johnRef: Option[ActorRef] = None

def receive = {
  case data:Data => johnRef match {
    case Some(reader) => reader ! data
    case None => context.actorSelection("akka://Post/user/John")
      .resolveOne(3 seconds)
      .map( reader => Deferred(data,reader)
      .pipeTo(self)

  case Deferred(data,ref) =>
    johnRef = Some(ref)
    ref ! data
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice explanation!

Comment: One more suggestion: I used a `var` for johnRef, but if you plan on going down the route of changing actor state, do a little reading on `become` to allow actor state changes in an immutable way